# Referencing the Date from a DateTime column in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have some tables with values, all of them containing a [created_at] column, which is of **DateTime** format, and I have connected them to my Calendar table, which contains **Date** values.

I want to create measures that I would then be able to filter by date (using filters from my Calendar like Quarter, Week Num, Month etc). The measure would be a COUNT() or a SUM(), very basic, but the connection of Calendar[Date] and Users[created_at] doesn't work correctly due to the different format (basically I apply filters from the Calendar table but only see the Totals in my graphs/tables).

I'm aware that I could change the [created_at] column to Date, or duplicate and then change that to Date, and this indeed would work, but I have a lot of tables and this isn't efficient. I can't change the Calendar[Date] to DateTime, as I would have to create all different DateTime combinations ("12/03/2023 12.00.00", "12/03/2023 12.00.01", "12/03/2023 12.00.02" and so on) and that also doesn't seem an optimal solution (plus I'm not even sure if that would group two users coming in on the same date but different hours if I tried to filter by day then).

Ultimately, I was thinking if there is a solution where I could reference that DateTime value as a Date (like adding "users[created_at].Date" or something to my calculation) through DAX, without adding a million new columns in Power Query?

PS. In the future I would like to be able to do the same thing with time (after I round up the time value), so if there is a solution that does both, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

So, the best solution hands down is to change the Created_At or have a date column based on that.

If you have a lot of tables, you can use tabular editor and run a script to create this for you. Here's an example of such script (note, this doesn't take into account that you already have relationships established between the date table and other tables, you'll need to delete them or edit the script below):

```
//Find the source column of the relationship (same for all tables)
var fromTable = Model.Tables.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Dates1");
var fromColumn = fromTable != null ? fromTable.Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Date"): null;


//Iterate all tables and if they have a created_at column and dont have a created_at_date, create one
foreach(var table in Model.Tables) {
    var createdAt = table.Columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name  == "created_at");
    var createdAtDate = table.Columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name  == "created_at_date");
    if(createdAt != null && createdAtDate == null)
    {
        createdAtDate = table.AddCalculatedColumn(
            "created_at_date",
            "Date = FORMAT(" + table.Name + "[created_at], \"dd mmm yyyy\")",
            ""
        );
        
        //Change the data type to DateTime
        createdAtDate.DataType = DataType.DateTime;
        
        //Check that a relationship doesnt exist 
        if(!Model.Relationships.Any(r => r.FromColumn == fromColumn && r.ToColumn == createdAtDate))
        {
            // Add the new relationship:
            var rel = Model.AddRelationship();
            rel.FromColumn = fromColumn;
            rel.ToColumn = createdAtDate;
        }
    }
}
```